# How to restore accidentally deleted .snap files?

Tags: snap

I thought the .snap files are just cached installation files and deleted them. How can I restore them? refresh and install don't seem to work. I like to keep the data of my installed snaps (uninstalling would delete those I assume?)

Here is one error message:

```
internal error, please report: running "antibody" failed: cannot find installed snap "antibody" at revision 10: missing file /var/lib/snapd/snaps/antibody_10.snap
```

Comment: Hi!  I don't use snaps myself, and can offer little help.  Other than trying to save a little space on your disk, what were you trying to do?

Comment: Also, [https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/how-to-prevent-data-loss-when-removing-a-snap/3930](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/how-to-prevent-data-loss-when-removing-a-snap/3930) may have a little information for you

Comment: @CharlesGreen I was just trying to save some space, but now space doesn't solve the problem at hand. :))

Comment: i did the same, was running out of space and thought these were installation files. now some packages are broken and can't find a way to reinstall them. has anyone had any luck with this?